# Resource allocation by Plug-and-Play BIOS

Tags: dos, bios, pci, pci-bus, plug-and-play

Plug-and-Play BIOS spec says that if you have a PnP BIOS, it can configure the hardware.

This means that your BIOS reads the resource requirements of all devices and configures them (allocates bus-resources to them).

Does a PnP *always* allocate resources(ie assigns I/O or memory addresses and irqs) to the devices embedded/integrated on motherboard?

Will a PnP BIOS(ie $PnP structure is present), *always* assign resources(I/O and memory addresses) to all devices present on mobo(ie embedded/integrated on mobo) *as well as* on PCI expansion cards.

Although the BIOS may not know how to 'configure' the non-embedded devices(ie devices not embedded on mobo), and will only configure devices embedded/integrated on mobo itself, it 'should' assign addresses(I/O and memory) and irq  to avoid conflicts in case a non-PnP OS like DOS is to be used.

My question is:

Does a PnP BIOS *must* assign the I/O, memory addresses and irq to *PCI expansion card devices* during POST, ie before loading and transferring control to OS bootlader ? Is it true  for all PnP BIOSes ?

Assume [Plug-and-Play OS] option is set to *No*. ie We told the BIOS that we do not have a PnP OS, but a non-PnP OS like DOS.

Some BIOSes do not have this option. Do they always allocate resources to *all* devices(ie both embedded ones and those on expansion slots)?

**Update on 2012-08-01 :**

*Section 2.1 titled 'System BIOS POST Requirements' of PnP BIOS spec v1a says:*

(I mentioned only the 3 points that are relevant to this post. The (*) marked info is *my* interpretation of the standard's statements. )

In order to achieve the goals of Plug and Play, the system BIOS POST is *responsible* for achieving the requirements listed below:

1. Configuration of all *'static'* devices *known* to system BIOS:

   At a *'minimum'*, this *includes system board devices*. It *'can'* also include 'Plug and Play ISA Cards' *and* devices located on EISA, ISA, *PCI*, or any of the other static bus architectures available.

   *In effect, the above statement says, devices 'embedded/integrated' on the system board on any static bus (e.g., PCI, ISA, or EISA).) *'must'* be configured by the BIOS, becoz *BIOS knows about *'all'* of the devices that are embedded on mobo, as a design part.* The system BIOS programmer *must* have incorporated the provisions to configure the devices embedded on mobo as a system design part.

   *Does this also include, 'cards installed in PCI/ISA/EISA card slots' ?*
2. BIOS POST Resource arbitration:
   The system BIOS must now be aware of system resource usage. Using the information provided through runtime services (described in a later section), along with resource information known to the system BIOS, critical resource conflicts can be avoided. *'Loading the operating system with a conflicting device disabled is better than causing a resource conflict and a possible system failure.'*

   *This seems *for ISA/EISA devices embedded/integrated on mobo or on ISA/EISA expansion card slots.* 
   Since PCI devices' resources *can't conflict* in terms of both I/O( or memory) address allocation(becoz the addresses are *not hardwired for PCI devices*, and hence in the *'hands' of BIOS* to allocate non-conflicting addresses.) and irq allocation(becoz PCI interrupts are shareable by design.), so *this means that 'all' PCI devices(embedded or non-embedded)will be initialized/allocated memory or I/O addresses and irq assigmnments.*
3. Support for both Plug and Play and Non-Plug and Play Operating Systems:
   The Plug and Play system BIOS POST *'must'* configure the system to operate with 'both' Plug and Play aware, 'as well as' non-Plug and Play operating system.* In non-Plug and Play environments, *'either'* the system BIOS *'or'* the appropriate system software (device drivers) 'must' configure 'all' devices (Plug and Play ISA Cards, PCI devices, etc.). *This will allow all environments to 'load exactly as they would on a standard PC compatible systems'.* However, in a Plug and Play environment, the system BIOS can now assist the operating system to perform features such as runtime configuration of system board devices and event recognition when system board devices have changed.

**All these 3 statements from the spec, seems to point that if a non-PnP OS is to be booted(e.g. DOS), then the system BIOS 'must' configure( or, allocate addresses and irqs, at least) 'all' PCI devices, whether embedded/integrated on motherboard(mobo) or not. For ISA and EISA devices, the BIOS 'must' not enable/allocate the resources for those ISA/EISA devices(whether embedded or non-embedded) which will result in conflicting resource assignments.*

Am I right in concluding *from above statements of the spec.* that: "If the BIOS must boot a non-PnP OS, it must enable (i.e., enable ie allocate resources) *'every' PCI device(whether embedded on mobo or on PCI expansion card slot)* in the system so that they are available for use by the OS and application programs"?

**Update on 2012-08-04 :**

Have a look at [chapter 12 of Linux Device Drivers 3rd ed.](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch12.pdf). The  author, at many places explicitly refers that I/O or memory addresses and IRQ assignments *will already be done by bios at the time linux kernel begins executing*, and linux kernel may tailor the assignment according to its needs.

Might be another reference that mentions what are we trying to reach.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart- Why this question is not related to programming? Just becoz I didn't make reference to any development environment, doesn't make this question out of scope. I need to develop a driver to be used from DOS, that's why I'm asking this question here. If the BIOS doesn't assign  I/O or memory addresses to PCI expansion cards during POST, then I must write a resource allocator to be used from DOS!. I do accept that this question may look like some hardware troubleshooting issue, but that's not the case. It is much more than that. :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's a valid programming question.

Comment: @jacks comment retracted :-)  If I could retract my close vote, I would. But for some reason [SO doesn't have that feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart- It's okay. I can just say, always poke the matter before jumping to a conclusion.

Comment: While PCI devices may share IRQs with **other** PCI devices, they cannot share with ISA devices (which don't support IRQ sharing).  This is a common problem if you have an ISA device with a jumpered IRQ setting, which the BIOS doesn't know about.  In those cases, you have to go into the BIOS setup and reserve the IRQ as Legacy ISA, which prevents the BIOS from using that IRQ for PCI or ISA PnP resource allocation.

Comment: Also, it is technically possible for a PCI device to conflict with an ISA device.  You can program a PCI BAR with an address that overlaps with a "low" ISA address.  In fact, I have seen this technique used to access a memory-mapped PCI device from real mode (reprogram the BAR with an address below the 1MB boundary).

Comment: @msemack- Now I understand why was IRQ conflict a hell for ISA system era, and even when PCI was introduced. But I *still* see *IRQ assignment and I/O address assignment* options(usually under *Onboard Devices Configuration sub-menu*) for parallel port, serial port, etc. even though these systems don't have ISA/EISA bus  ie even on PCs manufactured today. Why is this so? I mean why is there a need to reserve(or, explicitly assign) IRQs and I/O addresses for such devices like parallel port etc. even though they don't reside on ISA/EISA bus on a modern PC. These same PCs have option for ...

Comment: assigning IRQs either for PCI device or making it reserved. This option is usually unde PnP or PCI PnP sub-menu. Why is there a need to reserve IRQs and I/O addresses in a PC that doesn't have ISA/EISA bus?

Comment: You're right, the IRQ reservation screen is not very useful on a PC with no ISA slot.  Might be useful to force PCI devices onto a certain IRQ for debug purposes, or if the BIOS is dumb, and it's PCI init routines don't pay attention to COM port interrupts.  **The "real" answer as to why the screen is there:**  It's there in the vanilla BIOS delivery from Phoenix/AMI, and the OEM/mobo manufacturer does not bother to remove it.

Comment: @memsack- I think for some legacy devices(eg serial port, parallel port, Keyboard/mouse controller, etc.) these are assigned to be compatible with DOS era programs, which might have used fixed I/O or memory addresses, so that they can run w/o any modification. Just a guess. I also noted that these legacy devices does not *physically* reside on PCI bus, instead they reside on something called *SuperI/O chip* (this was the word actually used in a bios setup menu), and this chip  resides on something called *LPC interface* which is connected to PCI bus via a PCI-to-LPC bridge. The intel docs ...

Comment: ... say that LPC interface is the replacement for legacy ISA bus and all legacy devices now reside on this LPC interface. So, it seems that to *emulate* the legacy ISA bus, the bios also provide these settings to reserve IRQs and I/O addresses.

Comment: From a software perspective, LPC and ISA are pretty much the same thing.  LPC devices are mapped at a (semi) fixed I/O IRQ and you talk to them just like an ISA device.  (We implement custom LPC devices in our systems.)  LPC is mostly used for the Super I/O and BIOS flash chip.  However, newer Intel chipsets use a SPI interface for the BIOS chip.

Comment: Super I/O is a chip on motherboards that contains all of the "legacy" interfaces (PS/2, Serial, LPT, Floppy).  Some newer "legacy-free" PCs omit the Super I/O.  Here is an example of an SIO chip: http://www.smsc.com/index.php?tid=154&pid=104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "PnP OS" option is only relevant for ISA PnP devices, which are pretty much non-existent these days.  That's why you don't see the option much anymore.  It's basically a don't care on motherboards without ISA slots.  Might still have some relevance if you can set your serial port base addresses to "Auto".

The BIOS should ***always*** configure the PCI BARs and INTx-to-IRQ mappings.  It should do this regardless of the PnP OS option.  This includes both onboard PCI devices (e.g. integrated Ethernet), and PCI/PCIe slot boards.  I have never seen a (working) BIOS where you could boot to DOS and have non-configured BARs.

When the BIOS is setting up PCI configuration space, it will take ISA PnP information into account.  For example, if it knows an ISA PnP device is using IRQ 9, the PCI init routines should be smart enough to not map IRQ 9 to any PCI INTx lines.

Also, keep in mind that when your operating system loads, it is free to overwrite BARs and IRQ mappings.  Windows typically re-does IRQ mappings when it activates APIC and ACPI.  BARs are typically not changed, although there can be special cases like a PCIe Hotplug event which requires the OS to populate the BAR.

Comment: +1 for getting it clearer. :) So, in short this means that, in a PC with a PnP BIOS, when I boot into DOS(or any non-PnP OS), I can *assume* that *all* PCI devices(this includes both onboard PCI devices, and PCI/PCIe slot boards.) *will* have been allocated I/O or memory addresses and IRQs too, ie I can simply find a desired PCI device using its bus:dev:func and read its BARs to *get the allocated I/O or memory addresses and IRQ mapping*, and then simply issue x86 IN/OUT or MOV(whatever applicable) instructions to have data transfer to/from that PCI device. Am I correct?

Comment: I hope this is also true for *all* PnP BIOS - at least for PCs manufactured after 1995 or so. I 'm working with really old PCs. :)

Comment: I cannot find a formal guarantee of this behavior in the PnP or PCI specification documents.  However, I've been writing PCI device test software for DOS for 10 years, I have **never** seen a BIOS that deliberately did not configure all PCI BARs and IRQs during POST.  (I've seen some BIOSes that had bugs dealing with PCI-to-PCI bridges, but they typically had problems under multiple OSes, and could be fixed by an update from the mobo manufacturer.)

Comment: Your comment is correct.  You can interrogate PCI configuration space to get the BAR and IRQ values (either CF8/CFC or INT 1A).  If the BAR is I/O mapped, you can use IN/OUT.  If the BAR is a memory address, you can use memory operations (MOV).  **Keep in mind that memory BARs will be high addresses.  You will need to be in Protected Mode or Unreal Mode to talk to them.**

Comment: For reference, I just ran an experiment on a system here in the lab.  I booted a system and dumped PCI configuration space with PnP OS set to "No", and then repeated the experiment with PnP OS set to "Yes".  PCI configuration space did not change.  (I realize this is just one datapoint.)

Comment: This again proves that practical experience can't be beaten. :) Well. I'm using protected mode, so memory BARs with high addresses would not be a problem. As far as formal guarantee of this behavior in the PnP or PCI specification documents is concerned, I'm posting some points directly from PnP BIOS spec v1a, related to this post(under heading UPDATE) that will throw more light on the issue. I've also interpreted them as far as my understanding goes. See if we can deduce the 'formal guarantee.'

Answer (score -1):

The "PnP OS" option is only relevant for ISA PnP devices, which are pretty much non-existent these days. - FALSE!
This option has a great impact to the distribution of the interrupts in Windows OS! The experiment itself to disprove abovementioned statement is very simple!

Comment: This seems more like a comment to me... not really a constructive answer.